# count the "True" values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, counting

how to check if the selected columns in a dataframe  return **True**  and how to compare the count of **True** values with the column name count that is handling the count number of cells that are **NOT NULL**.

WHERE these selected columns can have a False  as value.

for this i used the below statement but i do not know how to compare it with the column  **count**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'dept':['dept1','dept2','dept3','dept4','dept5'],
                 'subd':['hndf','nbf','asx','qwe','def'],
                 'jju':['0','1','1','NA','1'],
                 'rob':['1','0','NA','1','1'],
                 'ans':['0','0','1','NA','1'],
                 'zsd':['1','NA','1','1','1'],
                 'count':['4','3','3','2','4']}


        dept    subd      jju     rob  ans  zsd count
0      dept1    hndf       0      1     0      1    4
1      dept2     nbf       1      0     0      NA   3
2      dept3     asx       1      NA    1      1    3
3      dept4     qwe       NA     1    NA      1    2
4      dept5     def       1      1    1       1    4 



df = df[df.loc[:,'jju':'zsd'].eq("1")]
```

how to continue from this ???

expected result :

```
0      dept3     asx       1      NA    1      1    3
1      dept4     qwe       NA     1    NA      1    2
2      dept5     def       1      1    1       1    4
```

Comment: In your case `1`  is `True` right?

Comment: yes `1` is considerate TRUE `0` is FALSE  and `NA` will not be counted

Comment: @enke the expected output is  highlight the records 2,3,4  or extract to a second dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `"NA"` by NaN values, then `sum` on axis, then use `eq` to compare to `count` column value to create a boolean mask. Then use the mask to filter `df`:

```
msk = df['count'].astype(int).eq(df.loc[:, 'jju':'zsd'].replace('NA', float('nan')).astype(float).eq(1).sum(axis=1))
out = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
    dept subd jju rob ans zsd count
2  dept3  asx   1  NA   1   1     3
3  dept4  qwe  NA   1  NA   1     2
4  dept5  def   1   1   1   1     4
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job,

```
df.replace("NA", np.nan, inplace = True)
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors = "coerce", axis = 1)
```

Output -

|  | dept | subd | jju | rob | ans | zsd | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | dept1 | hndf | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 4.0 |
| 1 | dept2 | nbf | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | nan | 3.0 |
| 2 | dept3 | asx | 1.0 | nan | 1.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |
| 3 | dept4 | qwe | nan | 1.0 | nan | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| 4 | dept5 | def | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 4.0 |